# Using getInitialProps in Next.js with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped, next.js

From the documentation, Next.js 5.0 announcement and various articles around on the internet it seems like Next.js supports TypeScript well and many people are using it.

But these threads suggest that `getInitialProps`, which is vital to Next.js apps, doesn't work:

- https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/3396
- https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/1651
- https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/23356

How can I fix it? In both class and functional components, when I do `ComponentName.getInitialProps = async function() {...}` I get the following error:

```
[ts] Property 'getInitialProps' does not exist on type '({ data }: { data: any; }) => Element'.
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

### Edit 2021/04/23: My answer below is also out of date

Please see [the Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript#static-generation-and-server-side-rendering) for the current recommendation for typing data fetching methods using new types and named exports.

tl;dr:

```js
import { GetStaticProps, GetStaticPaths, GetServerSideProps } from 'next'

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
  // ...
}

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  // ...
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  // ...
}
```

---

### Out of date (but functional) answer:

The above answers are out of date since Next.js now officially supports TypeScript (announcement [here](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9#built-in-zero-config-typescript-support))

Part of this release is better TypeScript types, with much of Next.js being written in TypeScript itself. This means that the `@types/next` package will be deprecated in favour of the official Next.js typings.

Instead, you should import the [`NextPage` type](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/d190f2e112bd4a767a21d1b0e9d61379d72ef1dc/packages/next/types/index.d.ts#L40) and assign that to your component. You can also type `getInitialProps` using the `NextPageContext` type.

```js
import { NextPage, NextPageContext } from 'next';

const MyComponent: NextPage<MyPropsInterface> = props => (
  // ...
)

interface Context extends NextPageContext {
  // any modifications to the default context, e.g. query types
}

MyComponent.getInitialProps = async (ctx: Context) => {
  // ...
  return props
}
```

Comment: How would that look like for components that are not pages?

Comment: @Alp Non-page components can't use `getInitialProps`. Therefore, you'd just type it like a normal react component (some interface for props, inferred return type is my favourite. You can also use `React.FunctionComponent`)

Comment: thanks. "some interface for props, inferred return type is my favourite" - can you elaborate a bit on that? not sure how that could look like.

Comment: @Alp `interface Props {
  propName: string;
};

const MyComponent = (props: Props) => (
  /* ... */
)
`

Comment: Does any know how to fix `@typescript-eslint/unbound-method`? It highlights `MyComponent` in `MyComponent.getInitialProps = ...`

Comment: @DanielCheung, have a look at my edit above. You should be able to use named exports as opposed to static methods now which will work around that eslint warning.

Comment: @JamesMulholland Can you please edit your example with code how to apply modifications to the NextPageContext query type.

Answer (score 25):

**EDIT: this answer is out of date since the release of Next 9. See answer above.**

The classical way to solve the problem is to declare `getInitialProps` as a static member:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<{...}, {}> {

  static async getInitialProps(ctx: any) {
    return {...}
  }

  render() {...}

}
```

When working with stateless components, you can declare a simple extension of `React.SFC`:

```
interface StatelessPage<P = {}> extends React.SFC<P> {
  getInitialProps?: (ctx: any) => Promise<P>
}

const MyComponent: StatelessPage<{...}> = (...) => ...

MyComponent.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {...}
```

Comment: Although usable, this answer is out of date since the release of Next 9. See my answer below on how to use official Next.js typings

Answer (score 12):

Types for Next.js are maintained in the [DefinitelyTyped project](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/next) which has a new version 7.0.6.

In order to use the new types, make sure you are importing them in your project:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/next@7.0.6
```

Here is how you type `getInitialProps` for a stateless functional component:

```
import { NextFunctionComponent, NextContext } from 'next'

// Define what an individual item looks like
interface IDataObject {
  id: number,
  name: string
}

// Define the props that getInitialProps will inject into the component
interface IListComponentProps {
  items: IDataObject[]
}

const List: NextFunctionComponent<IListComponentProps> = ({ items }) => (
  <ul>
    {items.map((item) => (
      <li key={item.id}>
        {item.id} -- {item.name}
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
)

List.getInitialProps = async ({ pathname }: NextContext) => {
  const dataArray: IDataObject[] =
    [{ id: 101, name: 'larry' }, { id: 102, name: 'sam' }, { id: 103, name: 'jill' }, { id: 104, name: pathname }]

  return { items: dataArray }
}

export default List
```

Here is how you type `getInitialProps` for a class:

```
import React from 'react'
import { NextContext } from 'next'

// Define what an individual item looks like
interface IDataObject {
  id: number,
  name: string
}

// Define the props that getInitialProps will inject into the component
interface IListClassProps {
  items: IDataObject[]
}

class List extends React.Component<IListClassProps> {
  static async getInitialProps({ pathname }: NextContext) {
    const dataArray: IDataObject[] =
      [{ id: 101, name: 'larry' }, { id: 102, name: 'sam' }, { id: 103, name: 'jill' }, { id: 104, name: pathname }]

    return { items: dataArray }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.items.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            {item.id} -- {item.name}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

export default List
```

If you review the [tests in DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/next/test/next-component-tests.tsx), you can get a lot of insights on how to use other variations of the typings for Next.

Comment: Although good, this answer is out of date since the release of Next 9. See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation

```
import React from 'react'
import { NextPageContext } from 'next'

interface Props {
  userAgent?: string;
}

export default class Page extends React.Component<Props> {
  static async getInitialProps({ req }: NextPageContext) {
    const userAgent = req ? req.headers['user-agent'] : navigator.userAgent
    return { userAgent }
  }

  render() {
    const { userAgent } = this.props
    return <main>Your user agent: {userAgent}</main>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution is declare type:

```
declare global {
   namespace React {
      interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
      getInitialProps(): void;
}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you're using TypeScript, you can use the NextPage type for function components**

[Nextjs DOC](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-initial-props#typescript)