# TypeScript NextPage function getInitialProp static method with @typescript-eslint/unbound-method

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, typescript-eslint

So I have the following code with typescript-eslint on with its recommended settings. I have read: [Using getInitialProps in Next.js with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49929268/using-getinitialprops-in-next-js-with-typescript)

```js
const X: NextPage = props => {/*...*/}

X.getInitialProps = async (ctx): Promise<unknown> => {/*...*/}
```

`X.getInitialProps` emitted this error:

> ESLint: Avoid referencing unbound methods which may cause unintentional scoping of `this`.(@typescript-eslint/unbound-method)

I believe this problem may be extended to, how to properly type static methods.

---

For those who aren't familiar with Next.js, `NextPage` has the (simplified) definition of:

```js
export type NextPage<C, IP = {}, P = {}> = ComponentType<P> & { // ComponentType is a React type
  getInitialProps?(context: C): IP
}
```

Comment: Seems like a known issue with ESLint: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/1256.  Pretty sure that describes your use-case as well.  Which implies you might just need to suppress that rule for your line of code?  That said, I am not hazarding any firm opinion on your code, but I don't see anything obviously wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GitHub repo of typescript-eslint has recently merged a pull request that fixes the issue https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/pull/1736